# What does setup.py install do to make code importable?

Tags: python, setup.py

When I download a package and run `python setup.py install`, the package becomes importable.  What does the command do that makes the code importable?

Comment: Have you considered reading the code, or the documentation, or just trying it and finding out? This is much too broad for SO as it stands.

Comment: I think it usually copies that package into a place where your python packages are stored, but it's been a real long time since I've dealt with a package that wanted `python setup.py install`, because thank goodness for `pip` and `apt-get`

Comment: @jonrsharpe  it is too board to ask whether  python setup.py install changes PYTHONPATH?

Comment: Depends on the specific `setup.py`.

Comment: Your actually question is *"What does python setup.py install do to make my source code importable?"*, which is too broad. The sub-question *"Does setup.py change the PYTHONPATH ?"* is a yes/no question, which isn't a great fit for this site, and you could have found out in the time it took you to write this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most cases, setup.py installs code into locations already along `sys.path` (which may or may not exist along PYTHONPATH). It doesn't modify `PYTHONPATH` or `sys.path`.

Generally, the input paths listed in setup.py are assumed to be relative to the setup.py script. For packages and modules, the output paths (where files are installed) are assumed to be standard python install location for third-party packages for the current python interpreter.